# Macro fails to separate sequences when some values are random

Tags: excel, vba

as a beginner in VBA programming I have a hard time figuring out what the problem is. The code works perfectly when the values ​​increase in order, but when there are values ​​in the array that are not similar then I get an error.
When the problematic values ​​are loaded, an error occurs `Run time error 9, subscript out of range` and this line is highlighted in the code `sequenceArr(counter) = arr(i + 1)` The main task of the code is to make short notations of long strings of numbers and to make a separation between different strings.
For example: i have box ID numbers: `M0054515,` `M0054516`, `M0054517`, `M0054620`, `M0054621`, `M0054622`, `M0054751`, `M0054752`, `M0054753`
When i run macro i get output result like this:
`M0054515-517 // M0054620-622 // M0054751-753`.
But when i have some random numbers in middile of ID number series i get an error... `M0046552`, `M0047396`, `M0047399`, `M0047802`, `M0047803`  instead of separated values i get run time error message.
At this link is an example version of my book, if anyone wants to help solve the problem.

For this job I use this code written a long time ago by another member of this forum

```
Sub Generate()


Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim arr() As String, result As String, letter As String, cellValue As String, tempLastElement As String
    Dim lastColumn As Long, counter As Long
    Dim firstColumn As Integer, targetRow As Integer, i As Integer
    Set ws = Worksheets("KreirajRadniNalog")
    firstColumn = 1
    targetRow = 1
    
    lastColumn = ws.Range(ws.Cells(targetRow, firstColumn), ws.Cells(targetRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Columns).Count
    ReDim arr(1 To lastColumn - firstColumn + 1)
    letter = Left(ws.Cells(targetRow, firstColumn).Value, 1)
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        cellValue = ws.Cells(targetRow, i).Value
        arr(i) = Right(cellValue, Len(cellValue) - 1)
    Next i
    
    ReDim sequenceArr(1 To UBound(arr))
    sequenceArr(1) = arr(1)
    counter = 2
            For i = 1 To UBound(arr) - 1
                 If CLng(arr(i)) + 1 = CLng(arr(i + 1)) Then
                    tempLastElement = arr(i + 1)
                    sequenceArr(counter) = tempLastElement
             Else
                    counter = counter + 1
                    sequenceArr(counter) = arr(i + 1) '<<<this line here is highlighted
                    counter = counter + 1
            End If
        
    Next
    ReDim Preserve sequenceArr(1 To counter)
    result = ""
    counter = 1
    For i = 1 To UBound(sequenceArr) - 1
        If counter > UBound(sequenceArr) Then Exit For
        If result = "" Then
            result = letter & sequenceArr(counter) & "-" & Right(sequenceArr(counter + 1), 3)
            counter = counter + 2
        Else
            result = result & "//" & letter & sequenceArr(counter) & "-" & Right(sequenceArr(counter + 1), 3)
            counter = counter + 2
        End If
    Next
    ws.Range("C4").Value = result
    
    
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Please, try better explaining what you want accomplishing by using of the above code. **In words**...

Comment: Please do not include links to external files in your question.

Comment: Sorry for not explaining it better, i updated my question with example values and result i get from my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is here

```vb
Else
    counter = counter + 1
    sequenceArr(counter) = arr(i + 1) '<<<this line here is highlighted
    counter = counter + 1
End If
```

because for every single number the counter is incremented twice and so exceeds the array size. However you don't really need arrays

```vb
Sub Generate()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, arr
    Dim lastColumn As Long, letter As String, tmp As String
    Dim result As String, i As Long, m As Long, n As Long

    Set ws = Worksheets("KreirajRadniNalog")
    
    Const firstColumn = 1
    Const targetRow = 1
    
    lastColumn = ws.Cells(targetRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    arr = ws.Cells(targetRow, 1).Resize(, lastColumn)
    
    result = arr(1, 1)
    m = Mid(arr(1, 1), 2)
    For i = 2 To UBound(arr, 2)
        n = Mid(arr(1, i), 2)
        If n = m + 1 Then
            tmp = "-" & Right(Val(Mid(arr(1, i), 2)), 3)
        Else
            result = result & tmp & "//" & arr(1, i)
            tmp = ""
        End If
        m = n
    Next
    result = result & tmp
    ws.Range("C4").Value = result
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I also understood what it was about, but I couldn't solve the problem. Your code works perfectly. Just how I would work manually when the code can't make a string. Thank you for your time! 
Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Please, try the next updated code. Since you did not answer my clarification question, I (only) hope that I could deduce what you want accomplishing...

```
Sub Generate()
   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Dim arr, sequenceArr, letter As String, cellValue As String, tempLastElement As String
    Dim lastColumn As Long, counter As Long, firstColumn As Long, targetRow As Integer, i As Long, j As Long
    
    Set ws = Worksheets("KreirajRadniNalog")
    firstColumn = 1: targetRow = 1
    
    lastColumn = ws.Range(ws.Cells(targetRow, firstColumn), ws.Cells(targetRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Columns).Count
    ReDim arr(1 To lastColumn - firstColumn + 1)
    letter = Left(ws.Cells(targetRow, firstColumn).Value, 1)
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        cellValue = ws.Cells(targetRow, i).Value
        arr(i) = Right(cellValue, Len(cellValue) - 1)
    Next i

    ReDim sequenceArr(1 To UBound(arr))
    counter = 1
        For i = 1 To UBound(arr) - 1
                 If CLng(arr(i)) + 1 = CLng(arr(i + 1)) Then
                    For j = 0 To UBound(arr)
                        If i + j + 1 > UBound(arr) Then Exit For
                        If CLng(arr(i)) + j + 1 = CLng(arr(i + 1 + j)) Then
                            tempLastElement = arr(i + 1 + j)
                        Else
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next j
                    sequenceArr(counter) = arr(i) & "-" & Right(tempLastElement, 3)
                    counter = counter + 1: i = i + j
                 Else
                        sequenceArr(counter) = arr(i): counter = counter + 1
                End If
    Next
    
    ReDim Preserve sequenceArr(1 To counter - 1)
    ws.Range("C4").Value = letter & Join(sequenceArr, "//" & letter)

    MsgBox "Success!"
End Sub
```

A more compact version, working with 0 based arrays:

```
Sub Generate2()
   Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim arr, sequenceArr, letter As String, cellValue As String, tempLastElement As String
    Dim lastColumn As Long, counter As Long, firstColumn As Long, targetRow As Integer, i As Long, j As Long
    
    Set ws = Worksheets("KreirajRadniNalog")
    firstColumn = 1: targetRow = 1
    
    lastColumn = ws.Range(ws.Cells(targetRow, firstColumn), ws.Cells(targetRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Columns).Count
    letter = Left(ws.Cells(targetRow, firstColumn).Value, 1)

    With Application
        arr = .Transpose(.Transpose(ws.Range(ws.Cells(targetRow, firstColumn), ws.Cells(targetRow, lastColumn)).Value))
    End With
    arr(1) = Mid(arr(1), 2)
    arr = Split(Join(arr, "|"), "|" & letter)
    
    ReDim sequenceArr(UBound(arr))
    counter = 0
        For i = 0 To UBound(arr) - 1
                 If CLng(arr(i)) + 1 = CLng(arr(i + 1)) Then
                    For j = 0 To UBound(arr)
                        If i + j + 1 > UBound(arr) Then Exit For
                        If CLng(arr(i)) + j + 1 = CLng(arr(i + 1 + j)) Then
                            tempLastElement = arr(i + 1 + j)
                        Else
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next j
                    sequenceArr(counter) = arr(i) & "-" & Right(tempLastElement, 3)
                    counter = counter + 1: i = i + j
                 Else
                        sequenceArr(counter) = arr(i): counter = counter + 1
                End If
    Next
    
    ReDim Preserve sequenceArr(1 To counter)
    ws.Range("C4").Value = letter & Join(sequenceArr, "//" & letter)
    
    MsgBox "Success!"
End Sub
```

Comment: Okay, let's try this. For each box I own I have ID numbers that increase in ascending order. If I have 50 boxes and the first one starts with the number M00100 and each subsequent number is incremented by the 1st code instead of writing all the numbers from M00100 to M00150 it should write M00100-150 as a result. And if there is an interrupt in the array of those 50 boxes, it should mark each interrupt with // and start checking the array again. Any number that cannot be incremented by 1 must be interrupted by //

Comment: @Mirko Stanisic OK. Understood now. I will adapt the code to return what (I understood) you want. I have something to do now (about 15 minutes) and I will solve it after...

Comment: @Mirko Stanisic Please, test the updated code and send some feedback.

Comment: You were very close Sir,  but again I got the same mistake for some unique strings. But it worked where my code couldn't. Thank you very much for your time and I'm sorry I explained it badly at the beginning ...

Comment: Didn't it generate the next string: "**M004689552//M004704396//M004704399-401//M004705802//M004733870//M004736913-916**". If this is generated, what's wrong with it? If you need something else, please post it **as it should be**... It is a matter a challenge, now... :)

Comment: You have `For i = 1 To UBound(arr)` but the test is `If CLng(arr(i)) + 1 = CLng(arr(i + 1)) Then` so when i = UBound(arr) then arr(i + 1) errors.

Comment: It made that string just right. But I tried with another set of numbers of 15 numbers that you are all different. It made the same error. But I have such a case with only one product that all the numbers are different. I really appreciate your work!

Comment: For example it can t generate string from this numbers: M005026522 M005026542 M005026561 M005026608 M005038730 M005039038 M005040060 M005040403 M005040447 M005040707 M005040808 M005040852 M005040882 M005040925 M005040953 M005040981 M005041044 M005041390 M005041634 M005042930
It shows same error as mine original code...

Comment: @CDP1802 Yes. It has not bothered by that if finishes in consecutive codes. It was exited by `If i + j + 1 > UBound(arr) Then Exit For`. But it is not when not consecutive... It used to be `-1`, but I do not remember in which circumstances I modified it... :)

Comment: @Mirko Stanisic Please, try the updated code. It worked well **only when the array was finishing in consecutive codes**...

Comment: @CDP1802 Of course, there... I am tired. I will close my laptop. It is very late in my country. Thanks!

Comment: There is an error  when i run code `For control variable already in use`  at this line `For i = 0 To UBound(arr)`   Yes it is late... Thanks for helping me, it mean a lot. Cheers!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238939/discussion-between-mirko-stanisic-and-faneduru).

Comment: @Mirko Stanisic `For i = 0 To UBound(arr)` did not exist. I corrected it when asked to test the updated code. Lake you can see, it became `For i = 0 To UBound(arr) - 1` in both variants.